# Include ElementorPro css into Wordpress custom page

Tags: css

I have created a custom page on WordPress, I have just copied page.php and added my slug at the end of page.php so my custom page is page-my-custom-page.php.

Inside my custom page I have a form with select boxes, buttons and other HTML elements.

I have ElementorPro plugin. What I want to do is to use the Elementor css classes on my custom page HTML elements.

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably this is not possible. From Elementor website: https://docs.elementor.com/article/165-can-i-include-elementor-pro-in-my-theme-hosting-diy-service

Comment: I don't use elementor but If you already have the plugin I don't see a problem with including it on a custom page.  You would just need to enqueue the CSS for the page using a page conditional.

Comment: That is correct. I was able to enqueue Bootstrap on my custom page. I just need to find out the css line for Elementor and that should do the trick. Thanks.